vb.net itext7 page break issues
I am having difficulties trying to skip to the start of the next page while generating a PDF report.
My code is formatting the report correctly, but I end of with a empty page at the beginning of my PDF file and my report is on a second page.
I'm using:

VB.NET
ITEXT7 - version 8.0.3

I am sure I have miss understood a concept and it is causing me to use the AreaBreak incorrectly.  Is there something else I need to do after I add the AreaBreak?
Here is the code that I am using in an attempt to generate the page break.  I can post the entire vb.net source code (203 lines) if someone wants to see it.
Private Sub PrintPageBreak(pTable As Table,
                           pBreakText As String)

    If Not mFirstPage Then
        mDocument.Add(New AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE))
    End If
    mFirstPage = False

Per request, here is my code.
Module MainLine
    Private mAddressesDt As New DataTable
    Private mPdfDoc As PdfDocument
    Private mDocument As Document
    Private mPdfFont As PdfFont
    Private mFirstPage As Boolean = True

    Sub Main()
        Dim lFolderName As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        Dim lFileName As String = String.Format("{0}\{1}", lFolderName, "TestPdf.pdf")

        CreateDataTable()
        GeneratePDFFile(lFileName)
    End Sub
    Private Sub GeneratePDFFile(pFileName As String)

        mPdfDoc = New PdfDocument(New PdfWriter(pFileName))
        'pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate())
        mDocument = New Document(mPdfDoc)
        mDocument.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 25)

        Dim lTable As Table = New Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(35)).UseAllAvailableWidth().SetFixedLayout
        lTable.SetWidth(mPdfDoc.GetDefaultPageSize.GetWidth - 25)

        mPdfFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA)

        AddHeaderCell(lTable, "Address Report", DeviceGray.WHITE, 12, 1, 36, DeviceGray.GRAY)

        Dim lPrevGroupingName As String = String.Empty
        Dim lCurrGroupingName As String = String.Empty
        Dim lBlock1 As String = String.Empty
        Dim lBlock2 As String = String.Empty
        Dim lBlock3 As String = String.Empty

        Dim lCount As Integer = 0
        Dim lDetailCount As Integer = 0
        For Each lDr As DataRow In mAddressesDt.DefaultView.ToTable.Rows
            lCurrGroupingName = lDr.Item("GroupingName").ToString
            If lCurrGroupingName <> lPrevGroupingName Then
                If lCount > 0 Then
                    ' something in progress so flush it out.
                    PrintDetail(lTable, lCurrGroupingName, lDetailCount, lBlock1, lBlock2, lBlock3)
                    lCount = 0
                End If
                ' skip to top of page and print the groupingname
                PrintPageBreak(lTable, lCurrGroupingName)
                lPrevGroupingName = lCurrGroupingName
            End If

            lCount += 1
            Select Case lCount
                Case 1
                    lBlock1 = String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}{0}{5}{0}", vbCrLf,
                                        lDr.Item("PeopleName").ToString,
                                        lDr.Item("Address").ToString,
                                        lDr.Item("CSZ").ToString,
                                        " ",
                                        lDr.Item("PeopleNotes")
                                        )
                Case 2
                    lBlock2 = String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}{0}{5}{0}", vbCrLf,
                                        lDr.Item("PeopleName").ToString,
                                        lDr.Item("Address").ToString,
                                        lDr.Item("CSZ").ToString,
                                        " ",
                                        lDr.Item("PeopleNotes")
                                        )
                Case 3
                    lBlock3 = String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}{0}{5}{0}", vbCrLf,
                                        lDr.Item("PeopleName").ToString,
                                        lDr.Item("Address").ToString,
                                        lDr.Item("CSZ").ToString,
                                        " ",
                                        lDr.Item("PeopleNotes")
                                        )
                    ' we have 3 ready so flush it out.
                    PrintDetail(lTable, lCurrGroupingName, lDetailCount, lBlock1, lBlock2, lBlock3)
                    lCount = 0
            End Select

        Next

        If lCount > 0 Then
            ' something is left, so flush it out.
            PrintDetail(lTable, lCurrGroupingName, lDetailCount, lBlock1, lBlock2, lBlock3)
        End If

        mDocument.Add(lTable)
        mDocument.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddHeaderCell(pTable As Table,
                              pCellText As String,
                              pFontColor As Color,
                              pFontSize As Integer,
                              pRowSpan As Integer,
                              pColSpan As Integer,
                              pBackgroundColor As Color)

        Dim cellman As Cell = New Cell(pRowSpan, pColSpan) _
                    .Add(New Paragraph(pCellText)) _
                    .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(pFontSize) _
                    .SetFontColor(pFontColor) _
                    .SetBackgroundColor(pBackgroundColor) _
                    .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER) _
                    .SetBorder(New SolidBorder(ColorConstants.GRAY, 2))

        pTable.AddHeaderCell(cellman)

    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintPageBreak(pTable As Table,
                               pBreakText As String)

        If Not mFirstPage Then
            mDocument.Add(New AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE))
        End If
        mFirstPage = False

        pTable.AddCell(New Cell(1, 10).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT) _
                         .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(12).SetBold _
                         .Add(New Paragraph(pBreakText)))

        pTable.AddCell(New Cell(1, 2).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER) _
                                         .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(12) _
                                         .Add(New Paragraph(" ")))

        pTable.AddCell(New Cell(1, 10).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT) _
                                 .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(12) _
                                 .Add(New Paragraph(" ")))

        pTable.AddCell(New Cell(1, 3).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER) _
                                         .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(12) _
                                         .Add(New Paragraph(" ")))

        pTable.AddCell(New Cell(1, 10).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT) _
                                 .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(12) _
                                 .Add(New Paragraph(" ")))

    End Sub
    Private Sub PrintDetail(pTable As Table,
                            pGroupingName As String,
                            ByRef pDetailCount As Integer,
                            ByRef pBlock1 As String,
                            ByRef pBlock2 As String,
                            ByRef pblock3 As String)

        If pDetailCount = 8 Then
            PrintPageBreak(pTable, pGroupingName)
            pDetailCount = 0
        End If

        pTable.AddCell(New Cell(1, 10).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT) _
                         .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(10) _
                         .Add(New Paragraph(pBlock1)))

        pTable.AddCell(New Cell(1, 2).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER) _
                                         .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(10) _
                                         .Add(New Paragraph(" ")))

        pTable.AddCell(New Cell(1, 10).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT) _
                                 .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(10) _
                                 .Add(New Paragraph(pBlock2)))

        pTable.AddCell(New Cell(1, 3).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER) _
                                         .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(10) _
                                         .Add(New Paragraph(" ")))

        pTable.AddCell(New Cell(1, 10).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT) _
                                 .SetFont(mPdfFont).SetFontSize(10) _
                                 .Add(New Paragraph(pblock3)))

        pBlock1 = String.Empty
        pBlock2 = String.Empty
        pblock3 = String.Empty
        pDetailCount += 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateDataTable()
        With mAddressesDt
            .Columns.Add("GroupingName", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("PeopleName", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("PeopleNotes", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("Address", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("CSZ", GetType(String))

            .Rows.Add("Group1", "Person Name A", "", "Person Address", "SomeCity, State, Zip")

            .Rows.Add("Group2", "Person Name K", "Person Notes K", "Person Address", "SomeCity, State, Zip")
        End With

    End Sub

End Module


Hi, yes please share your code snippet, because in normal use cases this should indeed work as you expect. So I expect something is playing tricks.

Maybe you call PrintPageBreak too often? The first call doesn't trigger the AreaBreak but the second does...

Sorry it taken so long, but I had a machine fail and needed to wait to get a replacement.  I'm up and going again and have added the code as requested.

Your methods PrintPageBreak and PrintDetail first conditionally add a new page to the Document mDocument and then some content to the table lTable.
In the For loop in your GeneratePDFFile method you call those methods multiple times without adding the table to the document.
Thus, in that For loop the only thing that is added to mDocument are all the new pages you create, and only after the loop, when you add lTable to mDocument, the actual report content is added to mDocument.
If, as you imply, the report looks good except for leading empty pages, you can simply remove all mDocument.Add(New AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE)) lines from your code.
If on the other hand you need page breaks between sections of your document, you first have to add the table with its current contents to the document, then add the AreaBreak, and then start a new table for additional content.

Thanks.  Based on this information, I was able to restructure some of the code and am now able to produce the report as needed.
